# O sistema está guardando estado onde não deveria

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estava na aba *Apresentadas* antes mas cliquei em Tags (segundo item do menu e foi para a página normalmente na URL *https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags*, mas buscando (digitando debug na caixa de busca) e depois clicando na tag [debug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug) esta página é mostrada. Voltando para a aba de Mais novas e depois visitando as Tags, funciona normal.

---

Aproveitando, a tradução de Apesentadas deveria ser **Destacadas**

Comment: Confirmado, fácil de reproduzir

Comment: Eu até esqueci de dizer que depois tentei sem fazer a busca para filtrar a tag específica que queria e clicar direto na tag, e acontece o mesmo.

Comment: Parece que o estado lembrado é a última aba visitada.

Comment: +1 para sugestão de tradução! Vim no meta justamente para reportar isso.